# how can i use div for inline?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show  like this

```
<label class="radio">
    <div class="option-title"><input type="radio" name="pickup" value="pickup" id="type_1">
        Pickup required (  Enter Address to calculate Price )
    </div>
</label>
```

but i need the inline using id instead of Enter Address to Calculate Price.
I using bootstrap.

```
<label class="radio">
    <div class="option-title"><input type="radio" name="pickup" value="pickup" id="type_1">
        Pickup required ( <span id="pickup_price"> Enter Address to calculate Price </span>)
    </div>
</label>
```

i use div is line break,So Any good coding is what should i write? Thanks you

```
<div id="pickup_price"> Enter Address to calculate Price </div>
```

Comment: can't getting what you trying to achieve, describe more and if possible provide a screen shot as well.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get what you are tying to achieve, but your question title regarding how to make a div inline is, you can specify the css as **`display:inline;`**

```
div{display:inline;}
```

This makes your div display inline.
But this won't take the block element property, so to make it display inline as well to take its block element properties, you can simply do,

```
div{display:inline-block;}
```